# How do I excecute a command for every split?

Tags: python, parsing, string-parsing

I am new to python, and am trying to filter a string that looks similar to this:

```
"{Red,Plant,Eel}{Blue,Animal,Maple}{Yellow,Plant,Crab}"
```

And so on for 100s of three word sets.

I want to extract the second word from every set marked by "{ }", so in this example I want the output:

```
"Plant,Animal,Plant"
```

And so on.

How can I do it efficiently?

As of Right now I am using `string.split(",")[1]` individually for each "{ }" group.

Thanks.

Comment: "I am using string.split(",")[1]": which sounds fine. What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
str_ = "{Red,Plant,Eel}{Blue,Animal,Maple}{Yellow,Plant,Crab}"
res = [x.split(',')[1] for x in str_[1:-1].split('}{')]
```

and produces

```
['Plant', 'Animal', 'Plant']
```

---

with the `str_[1:-1]` we remove the initial `"{"` and trailing `"}"` and we then split the remaining entities on every instance of `"}{"` thus producing:

```
["Red,Plant,Eel", "Blue,Animal,Maple", ...]
```

finally, for every string, we split on `","` to obtain

```
[["Red", "Plant", "Eel"], ...]
```

from which we keep only the first element of each sublist with `x[1]`.

Note that for your specific purpose, slicing the original string with `str_[1:-1]` is not mandatory (works without it as well), but if you wanted only the first instead of the second item it would make a difference. The same holds in case you wanted the 3rd.

---

If you want to concatenate the strings of the output to match your desired result, you can simply pass the resulting list to `.join` as follows:

```
out = ','.join(res)
```

which then gives you

```
"Plant,Animal,Plant"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TempestTheRed Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[i.split(',')[1] for i in str_[1:].split('}')[:len(str_.split('}'))-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is using regex, a bit more complicated, but it's a technique worth talking about:

```
import re
input_string = "{Red,Plant,Eel}{Blue,Animal,Maple}{Yellow,Plant,Crab}"
regex_string = "\{\w+\,(\w+)\,\w+\}"

result_list = re.findall(regex, input_string)
```

then `result_list` output is:

> ['Plant', 'Animal', 'Plant']

here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for regex in python
and an [online regex editor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python3

string = "{Red,Plant,Eel}{Blue,Animal,Maple}{Yellow,Plant,Crab}"
a = string.replace('{','').replace('}',',').split(',')[1::3]
print(a)
```

result is
`['Plant', 'Animal', 'Plant']`